# javascript mutually exclusive CheckBox issue

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a radio button that displays a list of records in a telerik grid. When the radio button is checked, it displays complete and incomplete records. However, the user wants a way of displaying only complete or incomplete records. I added two mutually exclusive checkboxes. The user can either check the complete or incomplete checkbox to display the data. It works fine on my local, but it does not work well on the server. The first time, the user has to click the checkbox two or three times before it can keeps the state. In addition, if complete is checked and the user checked incomplete next, the checkmark will go back to complete. The user has to do it a second times. What I am doing wrong here?

Here is the html for the checkbox

```
@Html.CheckBox("complete", SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.complete, new { id = "chkComplete", onclick = "chkInCompleteOption(1);this.form.submit();" }) <strong>Complete</strong>

@Html.CheckBox("Incomplete", SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.incomple, new { id = "chkInComplete", onclick = "chkInCompleteOption(2);this.form.submit();" }) <strong>Incomplete</strong>
```

//Here is the javascript

```
var completeCheck = '@SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.complete';
var inCompleteCheck = '@SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.incomplete';

 function chkInCompleteOption(e) {
        if (e == 1) {
            var cc = $('#chkComplete').is(':checked');
            var data = { "complete": cc, "inComplete": false };
                        var url = '@Url.Action("CompletedOption", "Orders")';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: 'text',
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                testComplete();
                                return true;
                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                alert("An error has occured.");
                                return false;

                            }
                        });

                    }
                    else if (e == 2) {
                        var inc = $('#chkInComplete').is(':checked')
                        var data = { "complete": false, "inComplete": inc };
                        var url = '@Url.Action("CompletedOption", "Orders")';
                        $.ajax({
                            url: url,
                            type: 'post',
                            dataType: 'text',
                            data: data,
                            success: function (data) {
                                testInComplete();
                                return true;
                                //  $('#chkComplete').removeAttr("checked", "checked");
                                //  $('#chkInComplete').attr("checked", "checked");

                            },
                            error: function (error) {
                                alert("An error has occured.");
                                return false;

                            }
                        });
        }


    }


function testInComplete() {
        if (inCompleteCheck == true) {
              inCompleteCheck =  $('#chkInComplete').attr("checked", "checked");
              document.getElementById('chkInComplete').checked = true;
        } else {
            $('#chkInComplete').removeAttr("checked");
        }
    }


    function testComplete() {
        if (inCompleteCheck == true) {
            completed = $('#chkComplete').attr("checked", "checked");
            document.getElementById('chkComplete').checked == true;
        } else {
            $('#chkComplete').removeAttr("checked");
        }
    }
```

//Setting the mutually exclusive value on the server side

```
public bool CompletedOption(bool complete, bool inComplete)

            if (inComplete == true && complete == true)
            {
                return false;
            }

            if (complete == true)
            {
                SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.complete = true;
            }
            else if (SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.complete == true && (complete == null || inComplete == null))
            {
                SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.complete = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.complete = false;
            }


            if (inComplete == true)
            {
                SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.incomplete = true;
            }
            else if (SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.incomplete == true && (complete == null || inComplete == null))
            {
                SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.incomplete = true;
            }
            else
            {
                SessionWrapper.currentEncounter.incomplete = false;
            }


            return true;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. The server side was being updated properly; however, the ajax was returning an error message every time it executed. The method on the server side was returning a Boolean when a string was expected. I've also set async and cache to false. I ran the application again, and it works.

//Change Method Signature from boolean to string

```
public string CompletedOption(bool complete, bool inComplete)
{
  return "true";
}
```

ajax post

```
$.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: 'post',
            dataType: 'text',
            async: false, //Added
            cache: false, //Added
            data: data,
            success: function (data) {
                  return data;
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert("An error has occured.");
                return false;
            }
        });
```